# Flutter - pass and initialize a parameter as an argument to PageView before build

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, frontend

I am trying to pass down a parameter(param1) to a ChildView when I route to ParentView from some other view, but parameter inheritance below does not work. If I put _pages within build context, the code will work with many unwanted boiling plates. BaseWidget is a StatefulWidget that handles generic arguments of Widget with ChangeNotifier.

1. Is there a better way of inheriting a parameter down to the ChildView before build?
2. Is there a better way of sending a parameter through routes other than using this code block of `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments`?

Below is a block of my non-optimal, failing code..

```
class ParentView extends StatelessWidget {
  int param1;
  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    ChildView1(param: param1),
    ChildView2(),
    ChildView3()
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseWidget<ParentViewModel>(
        model: ParentViewModel(parentService: Provider.of(context)),
        builder: (context, model, child) {
          param1 = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
          return Container();
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the parametes in the constructor of Childview as the code below, and you can use the param inside the Childview with widget.param.

```
class Childview1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final param;
  const Childview({
    Key? key,
    this.param,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InitialPage> createState() => _InitialPageState();
}
```